# How can pivot table/Raw data be divided into multiple worksheets

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I need to divide the PT/Raw (In Millions) data into multiple worksheets (based on employees-Approx 1000). I  used the attached code and sample file for that macro which goes per my requirement. However, existing code doesn't create worksheets on it own, however i have 1000 of students, so i want to create as many worksheets by the code as there are students. As i am new to VB so really not sure which part to change. I got the code online to create worksheets, however not sure how to insert it in original file. Any help would be helpful. Below is the code to divide the raw data into already existing multiple worksheet:

---

```
Sub copyPasteData()

Dim strSourceSheet As String
Dim strDestinationSheet As String
Dim lastRow As Long

strSourceSheet = "Data entry"

Sheets(strSourceSheet).Visible = True
Sheets(strSourceSheet).Select

Range("C2").Select
Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
    strDestinationSheet = ActiveCell.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Resize(1, ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Columns.Count).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets(strDestinationSheet).Visible = True
    Sheets(strDestinationSheet).Select
    lastRow = LastRowInOneColumn("A")
    Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets(strSourceSheet).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
End Sub


Public Function LastRowInOneColumn(col)

Dim lastRow As Long
With ActiveSheet
lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
End With
LastRowInOneColumn = lastRow
End Function
```

---

below is the code to create multiple worksheets

---

```
Sub AddSheets()


Dim cell As Excel.Range
Dim wsWithSheetNames As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wbToAddSheetsTo As Excel.Workbook

Set wsWithSheetNames = ActiveSheet
Set wbToAddSheetsTo = ActiveWorkbook
 For Each cell In wsWithSheetNames.Range("A2:A5")
    With wbToAddSheetsTo
      .Sheets.Add after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.Name = cell.Value
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
      Debug.Print cell.Value & " already used as a sheet name"
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
  End With
  Next cell
End Sub
```

---

Comment: `i have 1000 of students, so i want to create as many worksheets by the code as there are students` Pretty sure you can't have 1000 sheets XD

Comment: @pnuts I guess if each sheet only holds <10 bytes. I am on i7 with 16GB of ram and 30 sheets crawl my box down already XD

Comment: why don't you just keep it on one sheet and filter the pivot table as required?

Comment: @pnuts: what does it mean by limited by available memory (default) is one sheet? Does it mean, i can't create more than one sheet?

Comment: @teylyn: You mean filter the Pivot tables based on students and sending an email to that student with data relevant to him? If yes, that's would be the best possible approach. how can i do that?

Comment: @pnuts: so to create 1000 worksheets.. what should be the available memory?

Comment: @pnuts: Around 1K-3K lines per student... but that can be minimized too..and around 10-15 columns

Comment: @pnuts: what is the solution for that then? i can minimize the number of rows per student.or divide the students in multiple excel like 200 per excel? What change in the code should i make so that it create worksheets on its own with the available student name?

Answer (score 0):

Creating thousands of worksheets in order to email a subset of data to specific people would be an awful approach. Instead, use a Pivot Table to filter the data, then email the filtered data set.

If you filter the pivot table by person, use VBA to loop through the list of people copy the pivot table to an email, send and loop. Depending on your data you may not even need a pivot table, just a report sheet where the content gets looked up based on the student name.

I'm not going to write that code for you, though. You can find resources on pivot table specific VBA the web and any flavor of emailing content from Excel on [Ron de Bruin's site.](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/mail.htm)